# Achievements dropdown extremely slow to load

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, achievements-dialog

The achievements dropdown has become unbearably slow. All other Stack Overflow pages are fast, but clicking on the little icon in the top bar kicks off a long, loooooong wait for the menu to appear.

In fact, in the full version of the website the dropdown rarely loads at all, instead timing out. I only managed get it to load on the mobile version, but even there it times out more often than load.

This appears to be directly related to the documentation launch. I have several documentation upvotes in my achievements box, I suspect loading these is causing the performance issues.

Comment: We're aware, and fixing as I type this. Thanks!